# how to write header line only once in file in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created multiple threads using executor service in java.
On any error during the execution of these threads, I want to write some stuff to a file. So basically I maintain one file to maintain error messages of the treads.

I want to place a header line to this file only once as the first line.

Here is how my code currently looks like:

```
catch(exception e){
    String csv = "/tmp/data1.csv";
    FileWriter writer;
    try {
        File csvFile = new File(csv);
        writer = new FileWriter(csvFile,true);

        if(!flag) {
            flag = true;
            for(int i=0; i<metaInfo.length; i++){
                writer.append(metaInfo[i]);
                if(i != metaInfo.length-1)
                    writer.append(',');
            }
            writer.append('\n');
        }
        for (String aLine : line) {
            writer.append(aLine);
            writer.append(',');
        }
        writer.append(e.getMessage());
        writer.append('\n');
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am maintaining a flag to write a header line only once.
Now I am able to place header line only once into a file.
But as I am running many threads in parallel,I some times see the header is not placed the first line but at different positions.

What would be the way to solve this problem?

Comment: try synchronizing your `if(!flag) { ... }` block

Comment: put your header generating code in a method - synchronize that method

Comment: Initialize the flag value to false in the exception block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An application where multiple thread that each open the same file and write to it is not going to work.  You are going to get problems with output from different threads interleaving in unpredictable ways.

If you want to do this kind of thing, then:

- the threads needs to share a single `FileWriter` object
- they need to synchronize while accessing the object, and
- they (probably) need to use a mutex so that each thread gets to `write` a complete line (or whatever).

I would also recommend wrapping the `FileWriter` in a `BufferedWriter`.

---

So how does this relate to your question?

Simple.  If you implement your output code as I described, then the thread that creates the shared `FileWriter` can  write the header line before publishing the object to the other threads.

Answer (score 2):

You may use shared [`AtomicBoolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) for this case:

```
AtomicBoolean headerWritten = new AtomicBoolean();

// in parallelized code:

if(headerWritten.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
    ... // write header here
}
```

The `compareAndSet(false, true)` checks the current value and if it `false`, it changes it to `true` and returns `true`, otherwise returns `false`. The whole operation is performed atomically, but without locking. Thus it's guaranteed that header will be written at most once.

Also note that while I answered your question, your code has more problems which are denoted in @StephenC answer.

Answer (score 1):

You situation is something like this

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String ag[]) {
        new Thread(new MyRun()).start();
        new Thread(new MyRun()).start();
        new Thread(new MyRun()).start();
        new Thread(new MyRun()).start();
    }
}

class MyRun implements Runnable {
    static boolean flag = false;

    public void run() {
        if (!flag) {
            flag = true;

            //simulate doing some stuff
            try {Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random()*1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

            System.out.println("header");
        }
        System.out.println("other stuff");
    }

}
```

the problem is that `if(!flag){...}` block can be executed concurrentely, and while the first thread is still working, the second one could run faster and write lines before the first.

One possible solution is synchronizing those instructions like this

```
class MyRun implements Runnable {
    static boolean flag = false;
    static Object lock=new Object();

    public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (!flag) {
                flag = true;

                //simulate doing some stuff
                try {Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random()*1000));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                System.out.println("header");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("other stuff");
    }

}
```

or by using `Lock` objects, or putting everythin into a method and synchronizing the method. There are other 1000 ways to do this, I just wanted to give you an idea.